# Escopo de variáveis em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou com dúvida sobre escopo de variáveis em JavaScript.

Estou querendo construir um objeto chamado `Campeonato`.
Quero que um de seus métodos receba um texto de uma `textArea` e formate e forme um `Array` que seja um atributo do objeto.

Mas está dando erro! Parece que não consigo criar um objeto `Array` dentro do objeto. Talvez problema de escopo.

Segue o código:

```js
var bt_start = document.getElementById('start');
var textArea = document.getElementById('lista_times');

bt_start.onclick = function()
{
   if(textArea.value == "" ||  textArea.value == null )
   {
     alert('Preencha a textArea corretamente!')
   }
   else
  {

     var campeonato = new Campeonato();
     campeonato.getTimes(textArea.value);

     alert(campeonato.ArrTimes.length);

    function Campeonato()
    {
       this.getTimes = getTimes;
       this.arrTimes = new Array();

      function getTimes(textArea)
      {

           textArea.split("\n").forEach(linha => {
           clube = linha.split(';');

           time = clube[0];
           estado = clube[1];

           arrTimes.push(new Time(time,estado));

        })
      } 

    function Time(nome, estado)
    {
        this.nome = nome; 
        this.estado = estado;
    }
```

Comment: Em que linha dá o erro e qual a mensagem de erro? Por favor, adicione essas informações na sua pergunta, isso fará com que ela tenha mais chances de ser respondida.

Comment: Na verdade não roda o script

Comment: Aquela variável na função  Campeonato chamada arrTimes. Não consigo declará-la como um array(seus métodos não ficam visiveis no VSCode)  e não consigo formar um array como atributo do objeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque `arrTimes` não existe no contexto do seu `forEach`, mas sim em `Campeonato`. Para consertar isso, basta usar a keyword `this` para se referir ao escopo de `Campeonato`.

```js
document.getElementById("testar").onclick = function () {
  const campeonato = new Campeonato();
  const textArea = document.getElementById("teste");
  campeonato.getTimes(textArea.value);
}

function Campeonato()
{
   this.getTimes = getTimes;
   this.arrTimes = new Array();

  function getTimes(textArea)
  {

     textArea.split("\n").forEach(linha => {
       clube = linha.split(';');

       time = clube[0];
       estado = clube[1];


       this.arrTimes.push(new Time(time, estado));
      console.log(this.arrTimes);
    })
  } 
}

function Time(nome, estado)
{
    this.nome = nome; 
    this.estado = estado;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="teste" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br>
<button id="testar">Testar!</button>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, agora funcionou :)

Comment: @LorramRJ, a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta é marcando ela como aceita, clicando no sinal de visto (✓). Como você já atingiu 15 pontos de reputação, também já pode [votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de uma resposta ou pergunta, quando achar que foi útil. Veja: [Alguém me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Faça também o [tour], para uma explicação inicial de como o site funciona.

Comment: Aproveitando, segue um artigo interessante sobre o `this` no JavaScript: [Understand JavaScript’s “this” With Clarity, and Master It | JavaScript Is Sexy](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/).

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que pode ser usado um [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) nesse caso.

```
let times = textArea.split("\n").map((linha) => {
           clube = linha.split(';');
           time = clube[0];
           estado = clube[1];
           return new Time(time, estado);
     });

this.arrTimes.concat(times);
```